# Conditional formatting based on specific cells

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007, conditional-formatting

Is it possible to set conditional formatting based on a value written in a specific cell?

[image: Conditional formatting]

I would like to colour the rows of saturday and sunday and not colour the working days.

The condition is the letter in the second column, but I need to format the complete row.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's suppose the letter (L/F) is in **column B**, then:

- Select the first row.
- Open *Conditional Fomatting* / *New Rule*.
- On type of formula, select *"Use a formula"*
- In the box put `=$B1="F"`
- On the button *Format* select the format that you want.
- With the row still selected use the **Format Painter** to copy this format to the other rows.